# Show data between a date range

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

Greetings
I have the personal data of an individual including birth date
How do I get the information of people born between the date 1 and date 2?

date of birth is in a SQL Server database Compact
I get a record this way

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateConfiguration.OpenSession())
{
    var production = session
        .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Date", date))
        .List<Person>();
    return production;
}
```

Comment: Is this stored in a database?  If so, what type?  If not, more details?

Answer (score 5):

instead of `.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Date", date))` use `.Add(Restrictions.Between("Date", fromDate, toDate))`

Answer (score 1):

If you have these Object's Stored on a List than you could say ,

```
for(int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
 if(list[i].getBirthdate.Day == 1 || list[i].getBirthdate.Day == 2 )
  //DoSomething
}
```

But man ,you should be more Specific ,if these Information's are Stored in DataBase ,if Birth Date is Stored As Formated DateTime or whatever ,please be more specific and show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

By the tags in your question, it looks like you're using Nhibernate.  If you use Linq-to-Nhibernate, then you could use a linq statement like this:

```
var query = myISession.Linq<Person>();
var result = from entity in query
             where entity.Dob >= dob1 && entity.Dob <= dob2
             select entity;
return result.Count() > 0 ? result.ToList() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like extensions methods much more

```
var persons = GetPersonList();
var range = persons.Where(p => p.Dob >= startDate && p.Dob <= endDate);
```

Note that I know this is basically the same as using LINQ syntax, I just don't like linq syntax :).